# reload jquery datatable with url

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

```
var table;
$(document).ready(function(){
    table = $('#form_list').DataTable( {
        "ajax": '<?= base_url('report/get_form_report_data/'.$qc_form_id); ?>',
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    });
});
```

How can I reload this data table with new url. I have been trying this:

```
$('#division').change(function () {
    var qc_form_id = '<?php echo $qc_form_id; ?>';
    var actionUrl = '<?= base_url('report/get_form_report_data/') ?>'+qc_form_id;
    table.api().ajax.url(actionUrl).load();
});
```

But after changing the select box, showing an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: table.api is not a function

Answer (score 0):

$('#division').change(function () {

```
var actionUrl = 'your_url';
table= $('#your_table_id').dataTable();
 table.ajax.url(actionUrl).load();
```

});